# What is the term for an algorithm that performs better than the naive algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm

What is it called when there is an algorithm to achieve something more efficiently than a regular algorithm? For instance, there are some isPrime algorithms that are more efficient than trial division. Is there a name to categorize those algorithms?

Not a spigot algorithm.

Comment: What's wrong with "non-naive?" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm#By_design_paradigm

Comment: Optimized? As far as categorization goes, Big O notation typically does the job.

Comment: It's "Super-Bimbo-on-da-Move" I think.

Comment: I'd say "more optimal than..." or "optimized compared to...".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terminology and not programming. It probably belongs on http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'd go with "optimized" too.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of a classification for that but personally I'd go for sophisticated. It is the antonym of naive. It also sounds better then non-naive.